# Strcmp() Ошибка

Tags: c++, char

Не понимаю, в чем проблема. В справочниках сказано, что функция `strcmp(str1,str2)`, если `str1 > str2`, то компилятор вернет значение > 0 , если `str1 < str2`, то значение < 0 , если идентичны, вернет 0. Помимо 0, у меня все получается наоборот. **Дело не в длине слова. Например, когда в слове одинаковое количество букв и значение первой буквы при идентичных остальных меньше значения второй, компилятор возвращает наоборот, при `str1 < str2` " > 0" , при `str1 > str2` , " < 0" .** Пример приведен картинкой.

[image]

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std ;
int main ()
{
 int a , v  , z , q;
    char    str1 [] = "vzqa" ;
char str2 [] = "azqa" ; 
cout << strcmp(str1,str2) << endl ;

}
```

Вот код. Результат >0 , хотя при верном раскладе <0

Comment: Для начала убери из кода вывод неинициализированных переменных. Если не поможет, размести код и вывод текстом, а не картинкой. И проверь, что `a` действительно латинская, а не русская.

Comment: a точно латинская.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> В справочниках сказано, что функция `strcmp(str1,str2)`, если `str1 > str2`, то компилятор вернет значение `> 0`

Ну так это и происходит. Первая строка начинается на `v`, а вторая на `a`, соответственно первая строка больше и функция возвращает положительное значение. У тебя это 1, а на [ideone](http://ideone.com/y5cE3e) 21 - и всё как написано.

За исключением того, что значение возвращает функция, а не компилятор.

Comment: Почему 1 строка больше? Значение v , по сравнению со значением а , в памяти меньше, остальные же символы одинаковы.
v- 196883692
a- 1968934101
Разница (97139) , если вычитать

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, с чего бы это `v` было меньше чем `a`? Латинские буквы идут подряд,`a` в алфавите раньше, чем `v`. http://ideone.com/WZqJsE - вот 97 и 118.

Comment: Хм, начинаю понимать.. А что тогда означают те цифры?

Comment: Они , выходит, никак не влияют на процесс?

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, что ты объявил две неинициализированные переменные и вычел один мусор из другого мусора. Неинициализированные перемененные в си/си++ содержат мусор, а обращение к ним считается UB, которое вообще может к чему угодно привести.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Comment: А главное, ваши переменные `a,v,z,q` не имеют никакого отношения к вашим строкам...

Comment: @Harry, ты автора вопроса забыл позвать в комментарии...

Comment: А, ну да... но он-то все равно уведомление получит :)

Comment: Долго не мог понять, как связаны строки и переменные. Осознал - строки состоят из букв, являющихся именами переменных. Автору явно стоит почитать какую-нибудь литературу..

Comment: @Harry, нет, вроде не получит, т. к. тут есть не только его комментарии.

Comment: Эти переменные нужны были для вывода на экран. Предполагалось таким образом проверить сравниваемые значения, чтобы убедиться точно, что a>v . Но в итоге сравнивается не "мусор" ,а соответствующая цифра.
P.s Уведомление не пришло. Сам решил заглянуть.

Comment: @LongLiveTheKing, для этого символы надо писать в апострофах, а не объявлять переменные. `cout << ('a'>'v') << endl`.